# How to rename image from within code editor in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the name of Images such as `images/1.png` to `images/my_keyword.png` for On-Page SEO in my web pages.

Is there any way to rename image from within the code editor in VS Code?
Any VS-code extension to solve this problem?

Note: I want to change name in my `<img src="">`  tag and the corresponding action should rename that image in local directory too.

Comment: should it also update all other HTML files using this image? consider Dreamweaver

Comment: How can I do this in Dreamweaver? and which version of Dreamweaver is required for this functionality?

Comment: you should use a template engine so you only have 1 HTML/template to edit when you rename an image (or CSS file)